# Pearson correlation

Tags: correlation, sample-size, missing-data

Should the sample size n be equal when we are looking for simple correlation? I mean is it OK if variable 1 has a little more or fewer observations than variable 2? I am computing correlation between two variables...the *n* of one is a little higher than the n of other!

I am looking for correlation between 2 scales (psy tests). The n of one is a little higher than the n of another. I mean not ALL the respondents who filled up one form (scale) have filled up the other. There are some (very few though) missing.

Comment: Correlation only makes sense if values are paired. If one or more of your values in sample 1 is not paired with a value in sample 2, then those values can't be used in a correlation. Most of all, if no values are paired, correlation does not apply.

Comment: @Tania, you have _one_ sample, two variables.

Comment: As @ttnphns points out, "sample" is not the right term here. What are paired are values of variables.

Comment: Yes Nick! I am looking for correlation between 2 scales (psy tests). The n of one is a little higher than the n of another. I mean not ALL the respondents who filled up one form (scale) have filled up the other. There are some (very few though) missing...

Comment: So, you can't use any cases (observations, records) with missing values. Your software should take care of that somehow. (Depending on quite what your scale is, correlation might not be best, but that's another story.)

Comment: That is what I exactly thought: software should have taken care of it!I have already computed the correlation by using SPSS, but I wanted to be sure that it is ok if a few observations are missing in one of the variables, and n (s) are not matching exactly.

Comment: I don't know what you mean by "ok". You have some missing values; whether that implies a bias is impossible for us to say. Sample size $n$ as far as the correlation is concerned is the number of pairs of values included in the correlation; it can only be unclear or misleading to others if you think of this or report it as using different sample sizes.

Comment: Why remove mathematical formatting? It is cosmetic here, but it does no harm. (We are wasting time trying to make small improvements to your presentation if you keep reversing them.)

Comment: Nick, would you suggest I rerun the analysis by taking care of the missing values, and make the n (s) equal?

Comment: Sorry, but I am at a loss to know what you did that needs correcting. No statistical software worthy of the name will calculate a correlation from differing numbers of values for the two variables. Perhaps you should show us what commands you used and what output you got.

Comment: Many thanks Nick and @ttnphns! I will have to go back and check where did I go wrong:-) I might bother you again. TC

Answer (score 4):

**Yes, kind of...**

Yes, it is "fine." See this 10-case example, where case 5 and case 7 both have a missing:

[image]

Now, look at their correlation outcome, there are only 8 cases participating.

[image]

The reason is that Pearson's correlation requires the covariance between $x1$ and $x2$ to be calculated. If either one has a missing, there will be no covariance resulted, and the case is thrown out.

Now, to further illustrate, let us use select case to filter out the two cases:

[image]

And rerun the correlation again, the results are identical. This exclusion does not just happen to system missing, if you have assigned a user-defined missing, the case with that user-defined missing will also be excluded.

[image]

**But wait...!**

I said that it's "fine" because it's true that SPSS does screen out incomplete cases for you. But it is in no way solving the missing phenomenon for you. If there is any systematic reason that causes your participants to not answer a certain question, you correlation coefficient can be wrong. However, if you feel that they missed the answer in a random manner, then your correlation shouldn't be heavily affected, though you may lose some sample size and consequently power.

---

**Q:** *But - I ask you - please tell Tania about pairwise and listwise deletion of missings and under what button it is found in SPSS -- ttnphns*

**A:** Certainly. It would be necessary to illustrate with another example in which we have a new candidate, $x3$:

[image]

SPSS correlation analysis uses pairwise deletion by default, which means it'd always maximize the number of case in each of the pairwise comparisons. We have learned from above that the correlation between $x1$ and $x2$ has a sample size of 8 pairs. What about $x1$ and $x3$?

[image]

Turned out, it's 9 because maximally there are 9 pairs of data. Now, this can get inconvenient if you'd like to screen off the whole case and prevent it from being analyzed. In that case, you'll use list-wise deletion.

To call the option up, in the Correlation menu, press `Option` and then check `Exclude cases listwise`, then press `Continute` and `OK` to submit the test again:

[image]

Now let's run the correlation matrix again, you'll notice that all sample sizes are unified to 8; only cases that provide data to all the three variables are retained. Visit this [IBM FAQ](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21475199) if you'd like to learn more about the two types of deletion.

[image]

Comment: Very nice snapshots, gladden the eye! And the explanation. But - I ask you - please tell @Tania about pairwise and listwise deletion of missings and under what button it is found in SPSS.

Comment: @ttnphns, no problem. Revised.

Comment: Excellent (yes, really). Those shades, too... I feel like dragging it all to Flickr photostream.

Comment: @ttnphns, you're too kind. I use a screen capture software called [Snagit](http://www.techsmith.com/snagit.html) to do capture and post-capture touch up (like adding circles and arrows.) It also makes screen video, too. Pretty handy. (Disclaimer: I am not affiliate with this software's maker.)

Comment: A THOUSAND thanks @Penguin_Knight!!! You are just amazing...you have saved my life:-) I wish ALL teachers/ mentors are like you! And look at these beautiful & amazing snapshots. Awesome...